# Locating missing person (Bayes Theorem + Conditional Probability?)

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

So I came across a question that is kinda interesting. Here's the question:

Imagine we have 2 locator devices to find a missing person in the mountains. 
The probability that the missing person detected by device A is 0.8. Similarly, probability that the missing person detected by device B is 0.9.

But a single locator device is unable to locate the exact location of the person. In order to get accurate coordinates of the missing person, he must be detected by both locator devices.

Based on device A alone, the probability of detecting the exact coordinates of the missing person is 0.7 and similarly for device B with probability of 0.4

Find the probability of locating the missing person?

---

Attempt:

$P(A)= 0.8$ -> probability missing person detected by device A

$P(B)= 0.9$ -> probability missing person detected by device B

$P(C)= 0.7$ -> probability device A accurately locating missing person.

$P(D) = 0.4$ -> probability device B accurately locating missing preson.

$P(A \cap C) = 0.8 \cdot 0.7$? -> Probability missing person detected by device A with accurate coordinates/position. Likewise for device B?

It's been a year since I last touched probability. Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: sorry no understand, what does it mean by 'based on A alone' if they both have to detect him to get exact co-ordinates?

Comment: @Andrew Deighton Based on detection of device A alone, there is a probability of 0.7 to accurately locate the missing person. Yes, both devices must detect him to get exact co-ordinaries

Comment: so there are 3 states of detection?  Detected, location found, and accurate location found - is that right?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton yes

Answer (score 1):

Alternative assumptions: (a) each machine detects independently of the other with the given probabilities; (b) they both need to detect for any chance of location; (c) given they both detect, each machine can independently locate accurately with the given probabilities; (d) they must both locate accurately for the missing person to be found.  Then

The probability they both detect is $0.8 \times 0.9$

If they both detect then the conditional probability they both locate accurately is  $0.7 \times 0.4$

So the overall probability of a double detection and double accurate location is

$$0.8 \times 0.9 \times 0.7 \times 0.4$$

Comment: Thanks Henry, I will look into it more and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me (a) whether (given B fails to detect) device A accurately locates the missing person with probability $0.8 \times 0.7$ rather than just $0.7$, (b) whether the two devices act independently in detection, and (c) whether both devices detecting the missing person guarantees accurate location.

If the answer to all three is yes, then you could approach this by looking at the cases:

- Both detect the missing person with probability $0.8\times 0.9$.  Given that, the probability of accurate location is $1$
- A detects the missing person but B does not with probability $0.8 \times 0.1$. Given that, the probability of accurate location is $0.7$
- B detects the missing person but A does not with probability $0.2 \times 0.7$. Given that, the probability of accurate location is $0.4$
- Neither detect the missing person with probability $0.8\times 0.9$.  Given that, the probability of accurate location is $0$

That gives an overall probability of an accurate location of $$(0.8\times 0.9 \times 1 )+(0.8\times 0.1 \times 0.7 )+(0.2\times 0.9 \times 0.4 )+(0.2\times 0.1 \times 0 )$$

Comment: in order to get the exact coordinates of the missing person, both devices must detect him/her. location of the  missing person cannot be located exactly if only 1 device locates them. Because of this, I'm assuming both devices doesn't work independently of each other?

Comment: So what does *"Based on device A alone, the probability of detecting the exact coordinates of the missing person is 0.7"* mean?

Comment: the probability of device A locating the missing person accurately(exact coordinates) is 0.7. Based on detection from device A alone, the location of the missing person can be accurately determined with probability 0.7 and for device B a probability of only 0.4. If a missing person is detected by both devices, his/her location can be found accurately. I know it sounds contradictionary. But I guess the take away here is that you need both devices to get the exact location/co-ordinates of the missing person and 1 device by itself won't do it. I hope I clarified any confusion.

Comment: @misheekoh It still looks confusing and contradictory to me, but I will attempt an alternative answer with different assumptions